# Is there a limitation in oracle that prevents clob data from interchanging clob data

Tags: json, oracle, clob

```
procedure save_assessment1(
pClientID  IN number, 
pQuestionaire     IN clob,
pAnswers          IN clob, 
pClientID_res     OUT number,
pQuestionaire_res OUT clob,
pAnswers_res      OUT clob) is
begin 
      pClientID_res := pClientID;
      pQuestionaire_res := pQuestionaire;
      pAnswers_res  := pAnswers;
end save_assessment1;
```

I am trying to grab input `clob(Json)` and output the same i.e. `clob(json)`, but it returns nulls

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure looks fine (and works fine) to me

```
SQL> create or replace
  2  procedure save_assessment1(
  3    pClientID  IN number,
  4    pQuestionaire     IN clob,
  5    pAnswers          IN clob,
  6    pClientID_res     OUT number,
  7    pQuestionaire_res OUT clob,
  8    pAnswers_res      OUT clob) is
  9  begin
 10        pClientID_res := pClientID;
 11        pQuestionaire_res := pQuestionaire;
 12        pAnswers_res  := pAnswers;
 13  end save_assessment1;
 14  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> variable x1 clob
SQL> variable x2 clob
SQL> variable n number
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    save_assessment1(
  3    pClientID=>1,
  4    pQuestionaire=>'some input',
  5    pAnswers=>'some answers',
  6    pClientID_res=>:n,
  7    pQuestionaire_res=>:x1,
  8    pAnswers_res=>:x2
  9    );
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print n

         N
----------
         1

SQL> print x1

X1
-----------------------------------------------------
some input

SQL> print x2

X2
-----------------------------------------------------
some answers
```

Comment: Frankly Connor, I was able to make it work for snippets of text data as clob, However when I enter formed Json data in the 'IN' input parameter within the procedure, instead of the expected output clob, the result is a blank clob .

Comment: what size roughly in bytes ?

Comment: {"Assessment Form":"1",
     "Basic Info": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "fav_soup": "Carrot",
        "what_meal": "Lunch"
        },"Communication Support":{
        "com_support" :"Yes",
        "pref_lang" :"French",
        "interpretor" :"Yes"
        },"Youth Status":{
         "resource_connect" :"No",
         "youth_st" :"Enrolled in grade 1-12",
         "con_fam" :"No",
         "foster" :"No",
         "cas_name" :"NA",
         "cas_info" :"NA",
         "ystaff_notes" :"Lorem ipsum"
        }         }

Comment: File size is less than 1KB perhaps , however it feels like the Json formating might be the issue here.

Comment: Is there anything in your test case that does not match reality. Because I can't see how the proc has any knowledge of the contents at all. The database doesn't treat clobs as json (or vice versa) unless explicitly told to

Comment: I have used the json formatted contents above for both the input parameters, hoping to see the same files in the output, however the outcome is the reason for this thread. I cant think of anything else to add to the test case here.